# Access specific mail accounts using Microsoft Graph on a daemon process

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a windows service that imports support emails into a CRM from 4 different email accounts. I am currently using IMAP, but would like to move to Microsoft Graph.

After much investigating I am only seeing two options to make this happen:

1. Using a delegated permission: Implement a user interface to authenticate to the email accounts via OAuth (won't work for a daemon process)
2. Using an application permission: Get permission from my email admin to access ALL email messages in the company so I can process email from these four accounts (It will be a cold day in Hades when I get this kind of permission on a corporate level)

So, from what I can see, I am stuck. Can anyone recommend another option, or do I go back to IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

With 2 you could scope the permissions so your application only has access to those four mailboxes in question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access. For the corporate this would be the most secure option eg no user account/password or licence and you app is just restricted to email on those four account.

> So, from what I can see, I am stuck. Can anyone recommend another option, or do I go back to IMAP?

In security terms even option 1 is generally going to be better the IMAP (especially using basic auth) and you can use it in a daemon if you use the ROPC grant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc which is going to be the same as what you doing with IMAP.